# Чомор и лемор. Что означают эти слова и откуда они пришли?

Tags: лексика, диалекты

В северных деревнях нередко можно услышать из уст местных жителей забавные словечки, значение которых мне до сих пор неизвестно, но всегда было интересно его узнать. Например: *На чОмора оно тебе?* (Зачем оно тебе?) Или: *ЛЕмор надавал!* (выражение досады) Как пишутся эти слова, я не знаю, воспроизвела в соответствии  с произношением.

Вопрос: что означают слова лЕмор и чОмор и откуда они пришли???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чомор — лесной дух, леший, хозяин и хранитель леса. Герой уральских и северных народных поверий. Если его не задобрить, в лес лучше не соваться.

P.S. Чомор — не *табуистическое*, а прямое наименование конкретного персонажа языческого финно-угорского фольклора, который проник и в древнерусский сказочно-волшебный дискурс. Тем более, что слово *черт* известно с 15 века (не старославянское!), а слово *чомор* однозначно более древнее.

> Персонажами коми-пермяцких быличек являются чуды, леший, водяной, суседку, аналогичный русскому домовому или хлевнику, **чомор, аналогичный полевику или полуднице**, колдуны, знахари и другие. Вся эта нечисть приносит человеку несчастье или показывается не к добру, но изредка помогает ему.
>   [**Ссылка**](http://alldisser.com/part/ref-63424.html)

В различных источниках допускается известная путаница  между мифологическим лесным персонажем финно-угров **чомором** и древнерусским **чемером**. *Чемеръ* или *чемерь* — *venenum* — снадобье, зелье, отрава; *чемеритъ* — ядовитый, отравленный, магический; чемерица — лекарственное растение. Следует различать финского лесовика-чомора и русский чемер (зелье, ядовитая настойка; *стрела летяща съ чемеремъ*).

Если мы копнем в индийском направлении, то Брокгауз&Ефрон нам сообщают :

> Чумури
>   (санскрит. Cumuri) — в индийской древнейшей
>   мифологии (в Ригведе) один из враждебных
>   светлому богу Индре демонов или титанов
>   (dâsa или dasyu), упоминаемый почти всегда
>   вместе с другим таким же врагом Индры,
>   Дхуни. Близость обоих этих даса видна из того,
>   что имена их, подобно именам других парных
>   божеств (Индра-Варуна, Индра-Сома и т. д.),
>   образуют особое сложное слово, стоящее в
>   двойственном числе. Образы их не имеют в
>   Ригведе каких-либо ярких индивидуальных
>   черт.

[**Чумури**](http://enc-dic.com/word/cH/Chumuri-14423.html)

Чумури и чомор — яркая параллель в санскритском и финно-угорском реестре нечистой силы.

Остается добавить, что *чумури-чомор-чоморок* в русском языке практически совпадает со словом **сумрак**. Мара, мрак, морок и т. д. — противоположность светлым силам и сущностям, не правда ли.

```
Земную жизнь пройдя до половины,
Я очутился в сумрачном лесу,
Утратив правый путь во тьме долины.

Каков он был, о, как произнесу,
Тот дикий лес, дремучий и грозящий,
Чей давний ужас в памяти несу!

Так горек он, что смерть едва ль не слаще.
Но, благо в нем обретши навсегда,
Скажу про все, что видел в этой чаще.

(Данте, Божественная комедия)
```

Answer (score 3):

Нашел пока только одно упоминание о значении.
//=====
В русском языке, включая говоры, очень много табуистических наименований ***черта***. Д. К. Зеленин (19306) собрал их более сотни. Это, например: анчибил, анчутка, аред, аполлон, благой, враг, елс, долгий, игрец, неприятель, еретик, зеленый, лукавый, некошной, задав, лайтай, ***лемор***, лембуй, ***чемор***, шиш, куд, багаль, корнахвостик, голенький, черный, тяжкой, поганый, пекельник и многие другие. Каждое из этих наименований не случайно, и происхождение его может быть установлено: например: елс — это заимствование из финно-угорских языков, аполлон происходит от ветхозаветного имени князя тьмы Аполлион и т. д.
//=====
[Черепанова О. А. Мифологические рассказы и легенды русского севера(7) | booksite.ru](http://www.booksite.ru/fulltext/mip/hol/ogi/che/skye/7.htm)

Сразу скажу, я не готов поручиться за истинность трактовки. Очень часто т.н. исследователи русского фольклора валили в одну кучу все непонятные слова и имена и обозначения разных злых (а то и добрых) духов.

Кажется, где-то была версия, что Чомор - дух болезни, лихорадки. Найти сейчас не могу.
Лемор - тоже слышал, но не могу вспомнить, в каком значении - и знал ли это значение вообще.
Про лешего - не слышал точно.

Вспомнил! "лемор напал/одолел" - лень, нежелание что то-то делать, прострация.
Кстати, "лемор" на иврите "говорить". Но это вряд ли больше чем случайное совпадение.

//=====
Вотт еще про чемор.
[ЧЕМЕР (ЧЕМЕРЬ, ЧЁМОР, ЧОМОР, ЧОМЕР) | academic.ru](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/proverbs/10168/%D0%A7%D0%95%D0%9C%D0%95%D0%A0)

ЧЕМЕР (ЧЕМЕРЬ, ЧЁМОР, ЧОМОР, ЧОМЕР)
    Чемер ломает кого. Волг. Неодобр. Кто-л. хулиганит, совершает предосудительные поступки. Глухов 1988, 171.
    Понеси тебя (его и т. п.) чёмор! Прикам. Бран. Восклицание, выражающее гнев, негодование, возмущение. МФС, 109.
    Чёмор (чомор) знает кого, что. Перм., Прикам. Абсолютно ничего не известно о ком-л., о чём-л. МФС, 109; СГПО, 684; Мокиенко 1986, 181.
    Чтоб тебя чемер забил! Курск. Бран. Недоброе пожелание в адрес человека, вызывающего негодование, возмущение. БотСан, 118.
    Какого чёмора (чомора) надо? Перм., Прикам. Неодобр. Чего нужно? МФС, 110; СГПО, 683.
    Ни чёмора. Перм. Абсолютно ничего, нисколько. Мокиенко 1986, 170.
    До чемери кого, чего. Смол. О множестве кого-л., чего-л. ССГ 11, 100.
    Какого-то чомора. Перм. Почему-то, неизвестно отчего. СГПО, 683.
    Иди (подь, поди, пойди) ты к чёмору (чемеру, чомеру)! Алт., Перм., Прикам., Сиб. Бран. Восклицание, выражающее досаду, неудовольствие, желание избавиться от кого-л. СРГА 2-I, 174; Подюков 1989, 227; МФС, 15; СФС, 144; ФСС, 141; Мокиенко, Никитина 2003, 379.
    До чёмору (чомору). Перм., Прикам. О большом количестве чего-л. МФС, 110; СГПО, 683.
    Чемерь бьёт (ударит) в голову. Смол. О состоянии припадка. Смол. ССГ 11, 100.
    Чемерь тебе (вам, ему и т. п.) на язык! Смол. Пожелание плохого. ССГ 11, 100.
    Чемерь тебя (вас, его и т. п.) возьми (забей)! Смол. Пожелание плохого. ССГ 11, 100.
    Чемерь на тебя (на вас, на него и т. п.) сойди! Смол. Пожелание плохого. ССГ 11, 100.
    Не в чемерях (чимерях). Смол. Чрезмерно, с излишком (напр., о поедаемой кем-л. пище). ССГ 11, 100. /em> Чемер, чемерь, чомер, чёмор — 1. Нечистая сила, черт. 2. Насекомое, мошкара. 3. Брюшная болезнь животных, человека. 4. Нарыв, фурункул.

(С)Большой словарь русских поговорок. — М: Олма Медиа Групп. В. М. Мокиенко, Т. Г. Никитина. 2007.
Прямо скажу, я к Мокиенко-Никитиной отношусь с определенным недоверием, но тут - ряд из весьма убедительных поговорок. Ну никак там не "леший".

Comment: Брат с сестрой поспешили в чом. Чом находился напротив жилого дома, тоже в земле. Здесь хранилось разное добро: крынки, горшки, старые вещи, разная утварь. Рядом был ещё один чом - амбар для хранения муки и зерна в сусеках. Два чома сообщались лишь через небольшое отверстие, которым пользовался чомор. Правда, самого чомора никто никогда не видел, поэтому брат с сестрой безбоязненно забрались в чом, нашли там старые шубы, постелили их в дальнем углу и сразу уснули после трудной ночи.

Comment: Чомор перекликается с кикиморой и комаром, болотно-лесными жителями. Очень емкий образ, фантазии народ не пожалел. Однозначности нет, тем более в наше время.